# Puppet warp in PHP

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gd

I am looking for some way to resize certain areas of an object (i.e. car or a person's body) inside an image, using PHP with either GD or Imagemagick.
I was thinking in the lines of how the Puppet warp or Liquify works in Photoshop but have no idea where to start.

I did alot of research but can't figure out how to do this, if someone can please help or send me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to do image zooming like the one you showed on your example?

Comment: No, sorry the image is probably misleading. The image shown inside the red border is what it will look like after it is resized in php. I now want to resize the area below and above the red border in php to align with that area.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to write the PHP code to manually manipulate the byte arrays, i would suggest you to use an existing image processing library such as [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you, I've looked at that but doesn't seem to do what I have in mind. I've changed the description to get a a better understanding.